# How to use subquery in HQL using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a maven project using hibernate and jersey frameworks,
i've tried to create a subquery using hql, but its not working,
The code on DAO package is the bellow :

```
...
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append(" SELECT t.produtos FROM Tabela t WHERE t.id = :tabelaId ");

    if(parametro != null) { 
        str.append(" AND :parametro like (SELECT p.nome FROM Produto p) ");
    }

    try {
        if(tabelaId != null ) {

            Query query = em.createQuery(str.toString());
            query.setParameter("tabelaId", tabelaId);

            if(parametro != null) {
                query.setParameter("parametro", "%" + parametro + "%");
            }

            produtos = query.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
        }else {
            throw new DAOException("Voce deve informar a tabela!", ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST.getCode());
        }

    }
...
```

I receive a error message when i try execute the query.

The error message is:

```
<AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1386)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4316)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2134)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2062)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:813)
at
```

...

Answer (score 1):

This sentence:

```
AND :parametro like (SELECT p.nome FROM Produto p)
```

Is not supported by JPQL or HQL. Subquery is supported, but the problem is the `:parametro like` with a subquery.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have used native sql: em.createNativeQuery for this problem.